# Alternative plan of tf.floor

Tags: python, tensorflow

One of my operaction need integer, but output of convolution is float.
It means I need to use `tf.floor`, `tf.ceil`, `tf.cast`...etc to handle it.
But these operactions cause `None` gradients, since operactions like `tf.floor` are not differentiable

So, I tried something like below

**First**. detour

```
out1 = tf.subtract(vif, tf.subtract(vif, tf.floor(vif)))
```

But output of `test.compute_gradient_error` is 500 or 0, I don't think this is a reasonable gradient.

**Second**. override gradient function of floor

```
@ops.RegisterGradient("CustomFloor")    
def _custom_floor_grad(op, grads):    
    return [grads]  



A, B = 50, 7
shape = [A, B]
f = np.ones(shape, dtype=np.float32)
vif = tf.constant(f, dtype=tf.float32)

# out1 = tf.subtract(vif, tf.subtract(vif, tf.floor(vif)))
with tf.get_default_graph().gradient_override_map({"Floor": "CustomFloor"}):
    out1 = tf.floor(vif)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    err1 = tf.test.compute_gradient_error(vif, shape, out1, shape)
    print err1
```

output of `test.compute_gradient_error` is 500 or 1, doesn't work too.

**Question**: A way to get integer and keep back propagation work fine (value like 2.0, 5.0 is ok)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's not inadvisable to solve discrete problem with gradient descent. You should be able express, to some extent integer solvers in TF but you're more or less on your own.

FWIW, the floor function looks like a saw. Its derivative is a constant function at 1 with little holes at every integer. At these positions you have a Dirac functional pointing downwards, like a rake if you wish. The Dirac functional has finite energy but no finite value.

The canonical way to tackle these problems is to relax the problem by "relaxiing" the hard floor constraint with something that is (at least once) differentiable (smooth).

There are multiple ways to do this. Perhaps the most popular are:

1. Hack up a function that looks like what you want. For instance a piece-wise linear function that slopes down quickly, but not vertically.
2. Replace step functions by sigmoids
3. Use a filter approximation which is well understood if it's a time series

Comment: do you mean `floor` like a step function, I can try to find a linear function look like `_/—`, so the function will work as `floor` almostly

Comment: Yes, exactly. While you are training, make sure you increase the slope gradually.

Comment: I can't understand the meaning of `increase the slope gradually`. If I have this kind of function, why I need to increase the slope gradually. Or this function is geted by training? thanks

Comment: The function will have a slope. If you start with an almost-vertical slope, then the gradient will be zero everywhere except very close. If you start with a large-ish slope, then you can nudge the outputs to get closer. Then, you can start increasing the slope to be more like what you want. You can change increase after a few epochs.